# Closing a channel in Netty and waiting for its handlers to be removed

Tags: netty

I have a question about `channel.close()` and `channel.deregister()` in Netty 4.1.32 using `NioSocketChannel`.

I have noticed that the future returned by `channel.close()` is completed once the underlying socket is closed, before the pipeline is deregistered and the handlers are removed from it.

I have a use-case where I have to wait for the handlers to be all removed. I noticed that I can achieve it by calling `channel.deregister()` explicitly after the future from `channel.close()` is completed and waiting for the future returned by `deregister()` to complete. This however caused another issue: `channel.deregister()` doesn’t fire `channelInactive()` in the pipeline and it prevents the preceding `channel.close()` from calling `channelInactive()` as well.

Is this intended? If it is, can you recommend something to close the channel and safely wait for its pipeline to be completely torn down, keeping the normal flow of lifecycle events? (I do have some ideas like placing a handler at the front of the pipeline and waiting for its `handlerRemoved()`, or somehow tapping into the `HeadContext` of the pipeline, but I don’t really like either of them.)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you suggested as a way how to do this is basically the only way to do (adding a handler and then wait for handlerRemoved(...).

Comment: Would you be open to me making a PR to Netty to change the behavior? (Either only complete the close future once all handlers are removed, or fire channelInactive from deregister if appropriate?)

Comment: I think we may be ok to notify the "closeFuture()" once all handlers are removed but I would need to see the PR and talk with others.

Comment: Sure, I'll have a go at it then.